# javascript crash after multiple runs

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, webgl

I have a WebGL canvas that contains somewhere around 90k vertices and then some 'activity' files which basically tells at each 'time step' what color should every vertice have. This activity is splitted in a number of 'chunks' each stored in a separate file. After the activity from one file has past, I read the new one like:

```
    activitiesData = null;
    activitiesData = nextActivitiesFileData.slice(0);
```

Here `nextActivitiesFileData` is asyncronously read by an ajax call. Now all this works fine at first run, and sometimes even for some more runs, but somewhere along the 2nd -> 10th run interval it crashes. 
Now I assume this is due to the fact that the very large data that are used are somehow not garbaged fast enough. I've tried to be carefull always to use `var` and assigned not needed arrays to `null`.

Is there anything I can do to try to 'help' the garbage collection process? Could this crash be of any other nature?

Comment: When you say "crash", do you mean the entire browser crashes and closes?  Or do you mean the javascript in the page stops running due to a javascript error?

Comment: The browser is fine, only the javascript stops running, and the webgl canvas goes all black.

Comment: Is the browser reporting any JS errors in the error console or debug console?

Comment: No JS errors reported. However depending on the FPS and processor of the machine you run the script in, for very high performance machines the browser will also crash and the crash will occur faster, which leads me to think that the memory used for JS is somehow too fast occupied and garbage collection is not keeping up.

Comment: You should report browser bugs at the appropriate site. http://crbug.com, http://bugzilla.mozilla.org, http://bugs.webkit.org

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have the problem with data on the GPU not being freed fast enough?

There are two approaches to freeing memory allocated by the WebGL API.
If you create a WebGLBuffer object via gl.createBuffer(), the actual buffer is automatically deallocated only when the javascript object is garbage collected (there are no longer any references to that object), but this process is very hard to predict.

According to the latest spec http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/#5.14.5, there are "deleters" for most of the WebGL object types to give the programmer greater control of the memory.
Try calling the `void deleteBuffer(WebGLBuffer? buffer)` method when you no longer need the buffer.

**However**, if you by any chance have a problem with running out of memory on the CPU side, I apologize for this unrelated answer.